# Find matching rows if starting with identical name in 2 columns in R

Tags: r, match, startswith

```
data <- c("ABC_1", "ABC_2", "ABC_3", "ACB_1", "ACB_2", "ACB_3", "ABC_1", "ABC_2", "ABC_3", "ACB_1", "ACB_2", "ACB_3")
group <- c("ABC_group", "ABC_group", "ABC_group", "ABC_group", "ABC_group", "ABC_group", "ACB_group", "ACB_group", "ACB_group", "ACB_group", "ACB_group", "ACB_group")
df <- data.frame(data, group)
```

In this df I would like to select only the rows in which both data and group start with the same, without having to mention the matching name, meaning whatever is the "suffix" before the `_#` in `df$data` and the `_group` in `df$group`, so that I get to this

```
   data     group
  ABC_1 ABC_group
  ABC_2 ABC_group
  ABC_3 ABC_group
  ACB_1 ACB_group
  ACB_2 ACB_group
  ACB_3 ACB_group
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `subset` - create a  logical vector by removing the suffix part of each column using `trimws` specifying the `whitespace` as a regex (matching the `_` followed by characters (`.*`) and using `==`

```
subset(df, trimws(data, whitespace = "_.*") == trimws(group, whitespace = "_.*"))
```

-output

```
  data     group
1  ABC_1 ABC_group
2  ABC_2 ABC_group
3  ABC_3 ABC_group
10 ACB_1 ACB_group
11 ACB_2 ACB_group
12 ACB_3 ACB_group
```

---

If there are more than two columns to match, we may loop with `lapply`, do the `trimws`, and `Reduce` with `==`

```
subset(df, Reduce(`==`, lapply(df, trimws, whitespace = "_.*")))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   filter(str_detect(group, str_remove(data, "_\\d+")))
   data     group
1 ABC_1 ABC_group
2 ABC_2 ABC_group
3 ABC_3 ABC_group
4 ACB_1 ACB_group
5 ACB_2 ACB_group
6 ACB_3 ACB_group
```

Comment: chose the one with tidyverse - thanks :)

Comment: can I get your help again; I try the dplyr option and it doesn't work anymore. But the "string" does. But, I now want to keep except the ones with this condition (matching pattern).